# Multiple Applications Reference Same .DLL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have several modules that are stored in separate .dll files that multiple applications reference.

For example, I have a Login module that will be used across all of our custom applications.

What I want to setup is a directory dedicated for these .dlls on the client machine instead of having a copy for each in each of the applications directory.

Something like this:

- Program Files\My Company

  - Program 1
  - Program 2
  - DLL Library

I have been able to successfully get the DLL files to install to the correct directory through the installer project, but the applications won't load the assemblies when they run.

I feel like I might be missing something obvious here.

Comment: ^ Accepted answer: Change `folderPath` to the directory where the DLL is located.

Comment: That got it. Thanks!